# Python Version issue

Tags: python, macos, osx-elcapitan

I am very new to Python. But **I install Python 3.5.0** from pkg file downloaded from python.org on my MAC (OS X El Capitan).

Issue is that when I go to Terminal and issue command

`python -V`

It shows me **Python 2.7.10** why it is so and how can I remove that version

Comment: Have you tried `py -3 -V` to specify the one you just added?

Comment: when I put above got command not found

Comment: try "python3.5" in the terminal.

Comment: BTW, you can have multiple versions of Python installed. Don't uninstall the 2.7 version. Bad things will likely happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every Linux(Most of them Actually) comes bundled with python 2.7.x. So that's why it is showing you version 2.7.10.

Try running in terminal:

```
python3
```

You will get something like:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

where 3.4.3 is the python version.

same goes for python2.